# Listview does not scroll inside scrollview when scrollview scroll disabled

Tags: listview, scrollview, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following structure,

```
    <Scrollview> (scrollview scroll disabled and have refreshcontrol 
        <Scrollview> (this is horizontal scrollview works fine)
        </Scrollview> 
        <Tabnavigator> (this is react-navigation Tabnavigator)
           -Tab1 (React component have listview)
           -Tab2 (React component have listview)
        </Tabnavigator>
   </Scrollview>
```

My actual render method contains

```
<View style={styles.container} >
                {this.state.animating?(
                  <Loader animating={this.state.animating}/>
                ):(

                  <ScrollView
                  scrollEnabled={true}
                  removeClippedSubviews={false}
                  refreshControl={
                      <RefreshControl
                      refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                      onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
                      tintColor="#57C0B8"
                      title="Loading..."
                      titleColor="#FDC28E"
                      colors={['#57C0B8']}
                      progressBackgroundColor="#ffffff" /> }
                      >

                  <View style={styles.itemBlock, styles.itemDateBackground}>
                                <View style={styles.itemDateBackground}>
                                    <Text style={styles.itemDateHeadline}>
                                        Next To Jump
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                    </View>
                  <ScrollView style={styles.wrapper}
                  horizontal={true}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                  >
                  {nexttojumpdata}
                  </ScrollView>
                    <RaceTabs />
                    </ScrollView>

                  )}
              </View>
```

Now I want the Listview inside tabs to be scrollable. this is my listview inside tab1 and tab2.

```
       <ListView
             automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
              removeClippedSubviews={false}
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={(rowData) => {return 
              this.renderRow(rowData)}}
              enableEmptySections={true}
          />
```

The result am getting now is listview inside tabs are not scrolling. when I enable scroll on parent scrollview the whole layout will scroll. Also the navigation inside listview not working.

Any help ?

Comment: can you give the inner listview flex:1 and see if it works?

Comment: @FatemehMajd i tried flex:1 to inner list but no change.